# How to print PDF on AIX?

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript, aix

I need to print `PDF` files from `AIX 5.3 system`. i tried to used `Ghostscript` software to convert `PDF` to postscript files but i get the below message.

```
$ gs
AFPL Ghostscript 8.54 (2006-05-17)
Copyright (C) 2005 artofcode LLC, Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Xlib: connection to "local:0.0" refused by server
Xlib: Client is not authorized to connect to Server
AFPL Ghostscript 8.54: Cannot open X display `local:0.0'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
```

any help would be appropriated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a version of Ghostscript less than 8 years old.....

Basically your command line uses the display device (because you haven't asked for anything else, and that's the default) which on a *nix system is the X client. Clearly you  aren't running an X server, so it doesn't work.

You really, really need to be using something more recent, even if you get that ancient version working, the output will be not very good.

Comment: I tried to install version 9.18 but after i finished ./configure and start to run make i get the below msg: make: 1254-002 Cannot find a rule to create target | from dependencies.

Comment: Well AIX is a supported OS (though we do not supply a binary) and last I heard it was known to build and run. I would suggest you open a bug report stating that you cannot build on AIX. Do not forget to mention what tools you are using.

Comment: The " Cannot find a rule to create target | from dependencies" is because you are not running GNU make. You can either use GNU make (often gmake on non-GNU systems), or rerun configure with "--without-gnu-make" (as referenced in the --help output). Note that having been configure with "--without-gnu-make" you shouldn't attempt a parallel make build.

Comment: Thank you the Ghostscript now installed "Ghostscript 9.06" but it just working for maybe 1 or 2 mins after that it not shown the prompt "Just the welcome banner" so i should restart xserver service to working again and it stop working again after 1 or 2 mins, any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to use the X device ? I thought you said you wanted to print the PDF file. Note that 9.06 is several versions behind the current release (9.18). You should use the current version.

Answer (score 0):

`gs` without arguments tries to open a window, but you are not working in a graphical environment, or it is not set up properly.

I do not know if your ghostscript version is capable enough to convert pdf, but why not give it a try. Graphical environment is not required:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=myfile.ps -f myfile.pdf
```

More comfortably, see if you have `pdf2ps` available or if it can be installed. It is a shell script using `gs`. Just call it like `pdf2ps myfile.pdf myfile.ps`.